# Google Android app privacy policy Spam Email

Tags: android, google-play-services

We have received an email from Google that our app is violating privacy policy. It seems to us that it is a Spam Email. How we can verify?

They have the following play academy link: **playacademy.exceedlms.com**

Does **playacademy.exceedlms.com** have any relation with Google officially? Also, they have shared a google form for a survey, does google collect survey in such a way?

[image]

Comment: playacademy.exceedlms.com is the **Google Play Academy** website, watch this [video](https://youtu.be/xjRqFbTHUOQ) to learn more

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI - Any proof of the relationship to Google? When I search for _Google Play Academy_, it leads me to https://play.google.com/academy instead. The email is sent in the name of Google, so it could easily be spam.